# Unexpected MATLAB operator error when I initialize my function

Tags: matlab, function, audio, error-handling, syntax-error

I write a MATLAB function to do some processing in audio file and finally drawing the graph of audio.

`input_sequence` is a path of audio file.

```
function []= quantizer_DSP(input_sequence, B)
[y, Fs] = audioread('input_sequence'); 
MinRange = -1;
MaxRange = +1; 
QuantizerLevel = 2^B;
SignalRange = (MaxRange-MinRange)/(QuantizerLevel); 
y = y/SignalRange;
y = round(y);
y = y*SignalRange;

x=5000:5500;
plot(x,y(5000:5500),'r:');

end
```

When I use this function and use my audio file this error occurs:

> ```
> quantizer_DSP(F:\HAMED\Daneshgah\Term8\DSP\Majid~\majid\1,4);
>                 ↑
> Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
> ```

Comment: it would be much easier if you post the entire error message because the little arrow actually points at the column and row where it complains about something (whereas the path of your function is not such important;) )

Comment: you are also mixing up the variable `input_sequence` once as input variable and once as string to represent the filename you want to read...

Comment: yes , i get it , thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the error occurs in the line where you call the function, not inside the function itself. The function is never loaded.

You need to quote the path that you use as an argument:

```
quantizer_DSP('F:\HAMED\Daneshgah\Term8\DSP\Majid~\majid\1',4);
```